# http-mock naming conventions

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've setup a http-mock route using Ember CLI with the following command:

```
 ember g http-mock exercise-templates
```

Which then sets up the file `exercise-templates.js` which is defined as:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var express = require('express');
    var exerciseTemplatesRouter = express.Router();
    exerciseTemplatesRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send({
            "exercise-templates":[      
                {id: 1, name: 'Military Press', type: 'strength', muscles: [] },
                {id: 2, name: 'Situps', type: 'strength', muscles: [] },
                {id: 3, name: 'Yoga', type: 'class', muscles: [] },
                {id: 4, name: 'Pilattes', type: 'class', muscles: [] }
            ]
        });
    });
    app.use('/api/exercise-templates', exerciseTemplatesRouter);
};
```

So, when I then point the browser to `http://localhost:4200/api/exercise-templates` I was expecting to get my static JSON response defined above. Instead I get a 404. Then to my surprise I typed in `http://localhost:4200/api/exercise-template` (aka, without the 's') and it worked. Huh? Makes me wonder what is going on ... I mean I'm no Express guru but doesn't:

```
app.use('/api/exercise-templates', exerciseTemplatesRouter);
```

imply that the plural naming convention will be used?

Answer (score 0):

Ok well the answer turns out to be ... turn off "ember serve" and restart. Not sure why it wasn't refreshing but apparently the mocking does not always (ever?) gracefully refresh when updated. In any event, my expectation about "naming convention" appears *to be* the naming convention so I can happily report that all is right in the world again.

Comment: `ember serve` starts the node (express) server, then Broccoli watches your front-end files. So yes, every time you change your mock server code, you need to restart the ember-cli server.